# Small laggy when prepare exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

In my application, I had an infinite animation. Actually, it's a `TextSwitcher` animation running from left to right. However, whenever I tried to prepare the player, I got a jitter issue with the text's animation. Although it's just a few milliseconds, it caused my texts was like jumping from left to right. Here's the prepare video method:

```
private fun prepareVideo(uri: Uri): SimpleExoPlayer? {
    val simpleExoPlayer = SimpleExoPlayer
        .Builder(this) //                .setLoadControl(defaultLoadControl)
        .build()
    val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(uri)
    simpleExoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
    val eventListener: Player.EventListener = object : Player.EventListener {
        override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(state: Int) {
            if (state == ExoPlayer.STATE_READY) {
                playVideo(simpleExoPlayer)
            }
        }
    }
    simpleExoPlayer.addListener(eventListener)
    simpleExoPlayer.playWhenReady = false
    simpleExoPlayer.prepare()
    showToast("Prepare video")
    return simpleExoPlayer
}
```

Do you guys have any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite some time investigating, I found the issue is creating an `ExoPlayer` instance.

```
 val simpleExoPlayer = SimpleExoPlayer
        .Builder(this) //                .setLoadControl(defaultLoadControl)
        .build()
```

Just this simple blook took about `0.1` seconds to finish. As a result, it froze the animation for a short period of time. I decided to create it on splash screen and reused it whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you thinks problem in this part of code i can recommend you to try initialize your `SimpleExoPlayer` object in application class and use it's instance all across application.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
var exoPlayer: SimpleExoPlayer? = null

private fun setupVideo(uriString: String) {

    val appName = R.string.app_name
    val trackSelector: TrackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector()
    val userAgent = context.let { Util.getUserAgent(it, it.getString(appName)) }
    val sourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(requireContext(), userAgent)

    val uri = Uri.parse(uriString)
    val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(sourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri)

    exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector)
    exoPlayer?.prepare(mediaSource)
    exoPlayer?.playWhenReady = false

    pvPlayer.player = exoPlayer
}
```